# Getting this error after installation of tensorflow in windows 10

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Can you please share the steps you have followed. Thanks!

Comment: You might be facing this issue because either you are running 32-bit python or 32-bit OS and does your CPU supports AVX instructions? Also You need to ensure have the latest MSVC redistributable and that the Python binary is installed from official sources, not from Windows marketplace.For more information you can refer [system requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements).Thanks!.